# Php split value into different li classes

Tags: php

I use this code to display user entered data.
But all data is displayed on 1 single line separate by comma.

I want to display all separate data in an individual < li > class

How can I achieve that?

```
<?php if ( $this->showPros() ): ?>
    <div class="pros">
    <h4><?php echo $this->__('Pros:') ?></h4>
    <ul class="pros-ul">
    <li class="pros-li">
    <?php $isFirst = true ?>
    <?php foreach( $this->getProsCollection() as $pros )
          {
              $name = $this->__( $pros->getName() );
              echo ( $isFirst ? $name : ( ', '.$name ) );
              $isFirst = false;
          } ?><br />
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the `$name` in `li` tags:

```
<?php if ( $this->showPros() ): ?>
    <div class="pros">
    <h4><?php echo $this->__('Pros:') ?></h4>
    <ul class="pros-ul">
    <?php foreach( $this->getProsCollection() as $pros )
          {
              $name = $this->__( $pros->getName() );
              echo ('<li class="pros-li">'.$name.'</li>');
          } 
    ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```